# Unable to install gitlab on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am trying to install gitlab with helm on a kubernetes cluster which already have an ingress(cluster created by RKE). With gitlab, I want to deploy it into seperate namespace. For that, I ran the below command:

```
$ gitlab-config helm upgrade --install gitlab gitlab/gitlab \
--timeout 600 \
--set global.hosts.domain=asdsa.asdasd.net \
--set certmanager-issuer.email=sd@cloudssky.com \
--set global.edition=ce \
--namespace gitlab-ci \
--set gitlab.migrations.image.repository=registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/build/cng/gitlab-rails-ce \
--set gitlab.sidekiq.image.repository=registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/build/cng/gitlab-sidekiq-ce \
--set gitlab.unicorn.image.repository=registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/build/cng/gitlab-unicorn-ce \
--set gitlab.unicorn.workhorse.image=registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/build/cng/gitlab-workhorse-ce \
--set gitlab.task-runner.image.repository=registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/build/cng/gitlab-task-runner-ce
```

But the install fails while validating the domain with http01 test with cert-manager. For this, before running the above command, I've pointed my base domain to the existing Load Balancer in my cluster.

Is there something different which needs to be done for successful http01 validation?

Error:

```
Conditions:
Last Transition Time:  2018-11-18T15:22:00Z
Message:               http-01 self check failed for domain "asdsa.asdasd.net"
Reason:                ValidateError
Status:                False
Type:                  Ready
```

More information:

The health checks for Load Balancer also keeps failing. So, even with using self-signed certificates, the installation is failing.

When tried to ssh into one of the nodes and check return status, here's what I saw:

```
$ curl -v localhost:32030/healthz
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 32030 (#0)
> GET /healthz HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:32030
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable
< Content-Type: application/json
< Date: Mon, 19 Nov 2018 13:38:49 GMT
< Content-Length: 114
<
{
    "service": {
        "namespace": "gitlab-ci",
        "name": "gitlab-nginx-ingress-controller"
    },
    "localEndpoints": 0
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
}
```

And, when I checked ingress controller service, it was up and running:

```
gitlab-nginx-ingress-controller           LoadBalancer   10.43.168.81    XXXXXXXXXXXXXX.us-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com   80:32006/TCP,443:31402/TCP,22:31858/TCP
```

Comment: Hi @Stantanu.. Can you add the more description about your environment or any particular error you receiving...

Comment: @mohan08p Updated with error.

Comment: @Shantanu Deshpande, Have you checked events for ingress controller: `kubectl describe svc gitlab-nginx-ingress-controller -n gitlab-ci`?

Comment: @mk_sta Already checked. No errors reported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was resolved here - https://gitlab.com/charts/gitlab/issues/939

Basically, the solution as mentioned in the thread is not formally documented because it needs confirmation.